# Find function in j2ee web application

Tags: mysql, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, search

i'm developing a little market in a web application and i have to implement the search function. Now, i know i can use MATCH function in mysql or i can add some libraries (like apache lucene) but that's not the point of my doubt. I'm thinking about managing the set of results i get from the search function (a servlet will do this), cause not all the results should be send to client at one time, so i would like to separate them in some pages. I want to know what is more efficient to do, if i should prefer to do the search in db for every page the client calls or if i should save the result set in a managed bean and access them while the client request a new page of results. Thx (i hope my english is enough understandable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question you should be asking is "how many results can you store in memory"? If you have a small dataset, by all means, sure but you will have to define what "small dataset means". This will help as you call the database once and filter on your result in memory (which is faster).

Alternative approach, for larger/huge dataset, you will want to request to the database on every user page request. The problem here is that you call the database on each call, so you will have to have an optimised search query that will bring results in small chunks (SQL `LIMIT` clause). If you only want to hit the database once and filter the result in "memory", you will have to slot in a caching layer in between your application and your database. That way, the results are cached and you filter on the cached result. The cache will sit on a different JVM as not to share your memory heap space.

There is no silver bullet here. You can only answer this based on your non-functional requirements.

I hope this helps.

Comment: i think i have to evalutate LIMIT clause, but i think you are right on your answer :) there is no silver bullet here. where i will populate a bit more the db i will consider your suggestions, many thanks